# Oracle query to get how many days a record has certain status before today

Tags: sql, oracle

I need query to get how many days last time a meter has been online.
For example :

```
METER  PDATE  STATUS
ABC    1-Jan  off
ABC    2-Jan  on
ABC    3-Jan  on
ABC    4-Jan  on
ABC    5-Jan  off
ABC    6-Jan  off
ABC    7-Jan  on
ABC    8-Jan  on
ABC    9-Jan  off
```

If today is Jan 8th than the query will return : 3 (Jan 2-4).

If today is Jan 9th than the query will return : 2 (Jan 7-8).

My query below is working OK, but it takes 40-50 seconds if applied to the real table which has 5 millions records.
Please let me know if there are faster ways to get such data.

```
with last_off as
(  
  select meter,pdate lastoff from
  (
      select meter, pdate, 
             row_number() over (partition by meter order by pdate desc) rnum 
      from mytable 
      where status = 'off'
  )
  where rnum=1    
),
last_on as
(
    select meter, laston from
    (
        select a.meter, a.pdate laston, b.lastoff, 
               row_number() over (partition by a.meter order by a.pdate desc) rnum
        from mytable a, last_off b 
        where status = 'on'
          and a.meter=b.meter(+) and a.pdate < b.lastoff
    )
    where rnum=1
),
days_on as
(
    select meter, laston-pdate dayson from
    (
        select a.meter, a.pdate, b.laston, 
               row_number() over (partition by a.meter order by a.pdate desc) rnum
        from mytable a, last_on b 
        where status = 'off'
          and a.meter=b.meter(+) and a.pdate < b.laston
    )
    where rnum=1
)
select meter, dayson
from days_on
```

Comment: Consider using `LAG` or `LEAD` functions for this.  I don't have an Oracle instance handy to play around with it, but that may get you somewhere.

Comment: Also, you might be able to get somewhere by selecting `MAX` date where system is on and `MAX` date where it's off, then subtracting them.

Comment: As an aside, I would revise the use of `(+)`, maybe you don't need it at all.  It's supposed to do a left join, but because you don't use the plus sign on all columns of the left joined table, I think it's not actually doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
  select meter, pdate, status, 
      case when lag(status)  over (partition by meter order by pdate) 
                < status then 1 end chg1,
      case when lead(status) over (partition by meter order by pdate) 
                < status then 1 end chg2
    from mytable),
d2 as (
  select meter, max(pdate) do2 
    from t where chg2 = 1 and pdate < date '2015-01-09' group by meter),
d1 as (
  select meter, max(pdate) do1 from t join d2 using (meter) 
    where chg1 = 1 and pdate < d2.do2 group by meter)
select meter, do2-do1+1 days_on from d1 join d2 using (meter)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78f71/2)</sup>

Change value in line containing `date '2015-01-09'` to whatever value you want, `probably trunc(sysdate)`. Also change last line to:

```
select meter, count(1) cnt from t join d1 using (meter) join d2 using (meter) 
  where pdate between do1 and do2 group by (meter)
```

if you want to count rows from main table instead of simple subtracting days.

Comment: Good work! I think this is exactly OP is after. SQLFiddle demo link is down btw.

Comment: @toddlermenot - thanks. I checked sqlfiddle link twice - once after your signal and second time now. It works fine. Site sqlfiddle.com sometime does not respond, but link is correct. Again - thank you.

Comment: If I put the filter inside the subquery (... from mytable where meter='ABC' ...) and apply it to the real table with 5 millions records your query can reduce the time from 40 seconds to .. 1 second. Wow!

Comment: But by puting the filter inside the subquery I can not make the query as a view where I can change the filter separately. If I put the filter on the main SELECT query, the execution time is lot longer, that is 1 minute and 4 seconds. Currently I will be use it in a program codes so puting the filter inside the subquery is acceptable.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I just found a little bug in you query. If the ON day is only 1 day, then the d1 subquery has no record (null) because there is no date in CHG2 that < d2.do2. I think it should be <= d2.do2 ?

Comment: Yes, it seems that `<=` is correct in `d1` subquery. Tested it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f85a31/1).

Answer (score 0):

This would get the list of meters that have been on, and how many days they've been on.

(caveat: I don't have an Oracle instance to try this on as I'm writing it)

```
select maxon.METER,
       (maxon.maxdate - maxoff.maxdate) as dayson
  from
   (select METER,
           Max(PDATE) maxdate
      from MY_TABLE
     where PSTATUS = 'on'
     group by meter) as maxon,
   (select METER,
           Max(PDATE) maxdate
      from MY_TABLE
     where PSTATUS = 'off'
     group by meter) as maxoff
where maxon.meter = maxoff.meter
  and maxon.maxdate > maxoff.maxdate;
```

You could union a second query to get the meters that have been off, or just be more clever in how you interpret the subtraction result (i.e., do a `CASE` statement such that if the result is negative, it's off and if positive, it's on)
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Comment: It doesnt work that way. See my original post on the first case where today is Jan 8th. Your query will give 2 days (Jan 7-8), while the requested result is 3 days (Jan 2-4)

Answer (score 0):

**Data Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
    (METER varchar2(3), PDATE date, STATUS varchar2(3))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '01-Jan-2001', 'off')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '02-Jan-2001', 'on')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '03-Jan-2001', 'on')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '04-Jan-2001', 'on')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '05-Jan-2001', 'off')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '06-Jan-2001', 'off')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '07-Jan-2001', 'on')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '08-Jan-2001', 'on')
    INTO my_table (METER, PDATE, STATUS)
         VALUES ('ABC', '09-Jan-2001', 'off')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

You can make use of Analytical function called `lag`

**Query:**

```
SELECT meter, 
       pdate, 
       pdate - Min (pdate) 
                 over( 
                   ORDER BY grp DESC) + 1 AS daysoff 
FROM   (SELECT meter, 
               pdate, 
               status, 
               Max(grp) 
                 over( 
                   ORDER BY pdate) grp 
        FROM   (SELECT meter, 
                       pdate, 
                       status, 
                       CASE 
                         WHEN Lag(status) 
                                over ( 
                                  ORDER BY pdate) != ( status ) THEN 
                         Row_number() 
                         over ( 
                           ORDER BY pdate) 
                         WHEN Row_number() 
                                over ( 
                                  ORDER BY pdate) = 1 THEN 1 
                       END grp 
                FROM   my_table)) 
WHERE  status = 'on' 
ORDER  BY pdate ASC;
```

**Results:**

```
METER   PDATE   DAYSOFF
ABC January, 02 2001 00:00:00   1
ABC January, 03 2001 00:00:00   2
ABC January, 04 2001 00:00:00   3
ABC January, 07 2001 00:00:00   1
ABC January, 08 2001 00:00:00   2
```